# What happens under the hood when updating multiple columns on multiple tables with inner join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm in a situation where I have to increment all columns having an PK of table1 in all tables by 100000000000(it is a long story). As far as I know, I can update multiple columns from multiple tables with following query for example,

```sql
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.table1_id
SET table1.id = table1.id + 100000000000, table2.table1_id = table2.table1_id + 100000000000, table3.table1_id = table3.table1_id + 100000000000
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

To mitigate the negative impact on live queries ongoing, I thought that I'd better to execute queries like above for each table1.id by transforming all the ids in table1 into DML with regex(there are 100k rows in table1 and several hundreds of table2, table3, ... for each associated with each table1 id at the moment).

What I'm curious is, how it works under the hood?

- It would have significant negative impacts on another queries ongoing?
- What's the difference from a way of update each column in tables separately in a transaction? Above query doesn't work in an implicit transaction internally?
- What if I execute that query without 'WHERE' to update all the PKs of the rows in table1 with other tables' columns associated with those? It would have more negative impact? Why?

I'd like to know all the nitty-gritty about the process of those queries in MySQL.

It can't be nicer if you provide some official documentation about this situation or suggest another way to achieve this.